# How to find data for classifying grocery store items into categories?

Tags: classification

I know this doesn't sound like a good question but I've been googling and can't find broad range of data for grocery store items. As in, I want to be able to classify things like:

strawberry, banana -> fruit

potato, onion -> vegetable

cheese, yogurt -> dairy

detergent, dish soap -> cleaning supplies

I don't need it to be certain specificity(there could be a dozen categories or a hundred), but it's just daunting to classify thousands of items in a grocery store by hand when I'm trying to look into the data. What is the best approach?